# splitcontainer - animation while collapsing

Tags: c#, wpf

a grid with one row and two columns , i have write code when button clicked one of col become `width=0` and other `*`

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" Name="col1"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" Name="col2"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Button" Name="HidePanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="HidePanel1_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

code behind

```
DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            da.From = 100;
            da.To = 0;

            da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            col1.BeginAnimation(Grid.ColumnProperty, da);
```

i used splitcontainer in winform but because it doesnt support animation while collapse one panel i changed to wpf .

Comment: You are applying the animation to the wrong property. I suppose you want to animation the `Width` of `col1`, don't you? If so, it's not possible out of the box, because the width property is not a `double` but a `GridLength`. And there is no `GridLengthAnimation` class.

Comment: yes , your right . any alternative way to do (like Panel)instead of col?

Comment: Do you need to have two columns?

Comment: yes , one Hide with animation and other one fill that with animation too , like `splitcontainer` in `winform`but with effect while collapsing